# Making a tick mark into a list marker

Tags: html, css, list

I currently have a single row table consisting of four cells. Each cell contains a short paragraph and is started with a check mark symbol. The check mark currently sits indented into the paragraph, however, I would like it to sit to the left of each paragraph as if it were a list marker. The check mark I am currently using is an icon from 'font-awesome'.

I understand I could have made the four paragraphs into list items instead of a table set, however, am unsure of how I would replace the standard set of markers with check marks instead. What would would you recommend would be the most effective way to make such a layout?

Here is what I currently have:

```css
.services-offered {
        padding: 2%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 96%;
    }

    .services-offered td {
        padding: 0.75rem;
        width: 25%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .services-offered h2 {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .services-offered p {
        text-indent: 10px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <p>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
            </td>
                    
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <p>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</p>
            </td>
                    
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <p>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</p>
            </td>
                    
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <p>We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

I am a total newbie to the web design and development scene and this is my first solo project so please do tell me if you see any improvements I could make to my code etc, criticisms welcome!

Comment: **Don't use tables for layout.** Use a proper *sematic* list element is where you should start.

Comment: Thank-you for this advice. As I am still lacking experience the only way I could see to lay out the section was with tables but the clarification on here regarding the correct way using semantic markup has been hugely helpful so I am grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion.Just change your HTML code to this.

**HTML code**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </td>
</tr>         
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to aim for the HTML markup that makes sense. *Semantic* markup.

Then, style with CSS.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px; left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</li>
  <li>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</li>
  <li>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</li>
  <li>We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.</li>
</ul>
```

Note, using `flexbox`, we can enter all of our "cells" as `<li>`'s and then `wrap` them as needed, depending on our viewport size.

### Bottom line: Think about clean, semantic markup first.  Then style it as needed.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section p {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 125px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

section p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px; left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px; left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</li>
  <li>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</li>
  <li>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</li>
  <li>We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.</li>
  <li>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</li>
  <li>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</li>
  <li>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</li>
  <li>We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.</li>
  <li>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</li>
  <li>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</li>
  <li>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to use CSS values for checkmarks and assign the font-family property with CSS.  Here's a rough start for you.  There are several sites out there where you can find all the CSS values for Font Awesome characters with a simple Google search.

```css
ul {
  padding-left; 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  width: 1.3rem;
  margin-left: -1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<ul>
  <li>
    Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.   
  </li>
  <li>
    Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.
  </li>
  <li>
    If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.
  </li>
  <li>
    We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic advice! I am so sorry I did not reply sooner, major issues with my computer and now back up and running!

Comment: When using your edited html & css, its appears slightly differently in my browser. Firstly, the margin-left attribute seems to pull the first line of text to the left, why is this? If I change the value to 1.0rem then this seems to fix the issue but is that cheating? Also, the check marks actually just appear as a check box rather than a tick but all info I can find regarding the check mark says that the correct unicode is the code you have already used. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, I have sorted the check mark issue, appears I acccidntally pasted the link into my CSS. I do still have the issue with the margin-left attribute however.

Comment: Are you seeing it incorrectly in the snippet I provided or incorrectly after you've pasted it into your code base?  If the latter, then you have competing styles causing this problem and you need to use your inspector to find out what those are.  If the former, then let me know what browser/os and versions.

Comment: I do see it correctly in the snippet so I shall have to look into it more. Using an inspector is something I am totally unfamilar with. I assume brackets has this? Im running on Max OS Sierra and the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Chrome dev tools has an inspector. If you're going to be doing any sort of web development, this is your best friend.  Google has some very good online lessons on how to use the dev tools and the various inspectors. I'd recommend trying out those tutorials.

Comment: in Chrome: View->Developer->Developer Tools.  Or right click somewhere in your page and choose "Inspect" from the menu.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'll get onto that now!

Answer (score 0):

As people is already telling you yuo shouldn't use table as layouts. Obsolete. You may use many modern options.

However, if you still want to use it. with your example, first you need to insert the icon INSIDE the paragraph `<p>`.

Then you could give `padding-left` to your paragraph and negative margin just to the icon.

as this:

```css
.services-offered {
        padding: 2%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 96%;
    }

    .services-offered td {
        padding: 0.75rem;
        width: 25%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .services-offered h2 {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .services-offered p {
        text-indent: 10px;
        text-align: justify;
        padding-left:20px;
    }
    .fa {
      margin-left: -37px;
      
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table class="services-offered">
        <tr>
            <td>
                
                <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
            </td>
                    
            <td>
                
                <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</p>
            </td>
                    
            <td>
                
                <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</p>
            </td>
                    
            <td>
                
                <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank-you Alvaro, I totally appreciate the advice on working on semantic markup and now I have seen examples applying semantic markup to my situation, it all makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want reposition the element. To do so you will need to take the checkmark element out of flow and absolutely position it inside the td with the copy.

1. Make sure the parent element (in this case the td) has the CSS property `position: relative` this is to make sure that when we set the checkmark's position to absolute it stays inside the td.
2. Absolutely position your checkmark with `position: absolute` ... This will leave the checkmark near the top-left of the box but no longer affects the flow of the text.
3. Now we need to use the CSS properties `top` and `left` to move the checkmark around. I chose `left: 7px` and `top: 31px` to fit it snuggly inside the text-indent
4. Keep messing with it until you get what you want.

Here is the modified code:

```
<style>
.services-offered {
  padding: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 96%;
}

.services-offered td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.services-offered h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.services-offered p {
  text-indent: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 31px;
}
</style>

<table class="services-offered">
<tr>
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check checkmark"></i>
        <p>Installation and commission of natural gas central heating systems.</p>
    </td>

    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check checkmark"></i>
        <p>Routine servicing of <span>all</span> natural gas appliances including warm air units.</p>
    </td>

    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check checkmark"></i>
        <p>If any of your gas appliances breakdown, we provide a 7 day a week callout service to get them back up and running.</p>
    </td>

    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check checkmark"></i>
        <p>We can provide gas safety landlord certification for all gas appliances in your properties.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```